# Dart Test client- side HTML configuration

Tags: dart, dart-html

I understand that the **package:unittest/unittest.dart** is deprecated and the new package is **package:test/test.dart**.

Which are the equivalent of the library **package:unittest/html_config.dart** and the **useHtmlConfiguration()** function in the new **test.dart** framework.

Thanks.

Note: I am reading an outdated book ("Dart in Action"). So far I have been able to match the deprecated parts with the new standard parts of Dart.
Except now that I am reading the section of Unit-Test.

[source code](https://github.com/ram535/DartWebApps/tree/master/package_list/wa14)

```
.
├── PackList.dart
├── PackList.html
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
├── styles.css
└── test
    ├── PackList_test.dart
    └── PackList_test.html
```

I am trying to check if the value that the constructor return is not NULL.

```
import "package:test/test.dart";
import "../PackList.dart" as packListApp;

main() {
  test("PackItem constructor", () {
    var item = new packListApp.PackItem("Towel");
    expect(item, isNotNull);
  });
}
```

The source code works.

This is just an excersice to understand how the test framework works.

I expect **item** to be a new object.

With this properties initialized after **var item = new packListApp.PackItem("Towel");**

```
 print(packItem.uiElement); //Towel
 print(packItem.itemText);  //div
```

The problem is that I don't know how do related the **html** part of my source code with the test.

When I run this test, I got this errors.

```
 pub run test
00:00 +0 -1: loading test/PackList_test.dart [E]                                                   
  Failed to load "test/PackList_test.dart":
  Unable to spawn isolate: The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.
  PackList.dart: line 1 pos 1: library handler failed
  import "dart:html";
  ^
00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

If I add **@TestOn("dartium")**, I got this message.

```
pub run test
No tests ran.
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no equivalent. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to check the value that a constructor return is not NULL.

Comment: The test package has really great docs. I think you should start there. Test files should be in the `test` directory and be named `*_test.dart` and `*_test.html`.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't figure it out how to do it.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What is the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: I updated and add the answer to your question at the end of the description of the problem. But I explained short here. The problem is that I don't know how to related my html source file with the test.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what the problem is. I assume you either get an error for `new packListApp.PackItem("Towel")` or `expect(item, isNotNull)` will succeed.

Comment: I am using Dartium and I try @TestOn(dartium) on top of the test file but it did not work.

Comment: "did not work" is quite vague. What exactly is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: well the object is create after the source code communicate with the browser. I test my source code manually and it works.

Comment: Sorry, can't make any sense of this comment.

Comment: okay sorry for my bad communication skills. How to make aware the test that the object is create after it runs in the browser (Dartium)

Comment: I guess you need to fix the Dart script tag in your HTML file like explained in the test package docs about browser tests. Then you need to run `pub run test -pdartium` otherwise only VM tests are run.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the tags like in the test package docs and run the command pub run test -pdartium. Now I have this error **Failed to load "test/PackList_test.dart": Dartium exited before connecting**. It seems like it is NOT loading the html file.

Comment: Did you fix the script tag like explained in https://github.com/dart-lang/test#running-tests-with-custom-html? (`<link rel="x-dart-test" ...`)

Comment: yes I did that.

Answer (score 0):

`pub run test` just runs VM tests. If you want to run browser tests, you need to explicitly tell it like

```
pub run test -pdartium
```

The `my_test.html` needs to contain

```
<link rel="x-dart-test" href="my_test.dart">
```

instead of a normal Dart script tag

Comment: I made those modification but it was not successful. I am moving forward and keep learning Dart. I hope in the future I figure it out what I did wrong. Thanks for all your help and for guide me to the right path.

Comment: I see. I interpreted your last comment as if it is working now. I don't know what else to suggest.